# SQL DB2 journal entries directly on iSeries

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, journal

A while ago I came across an SQL statement that can be used on the iSeries/DB2 to extract data directly from database journals. It worked without having to use DSPJRN etc. It invoked a stored procedure and the results came directly back to the SQL session. Unfortunately I have since lost the info.

Does anyone know the stored procedure name and how to write the SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. It works via a UDTF - user defined table function - provided by IBM.

The format is as follows. Only the first 2 parameters are required. There is a decent blog about it here: http://ibmsystemsmag.blogs.com/i_can/2010/11/

select * from table (Display_Journal(
  'journLib',     'Journal',      -- Journal library and name --
  'receiverLib', 'Receiver',         -- Receiver library and name --
  CAST(null as TIMESTAMP),           -- Starting timestamp --
  CAST(null as DECIMAL(21,0)),       -- Starting sequence number --
  '',                                -- Journal codes --
  '',                                -- Journal entries --
  '','',                             -- Object library, Object name --
  '','',                             -- Object type, Object member --
  '',                                -- User --
  '',                                -- Job --
  ''                                 -- Program --
) ) as x

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you describe but the Tools/400 [EXPJRNE](http://www.tools400.de/English/Freeware/Utilities/utilities.html) freeware utility could be called as a stored procedure or could be wrapped in a custom stored procedure that would return the result set as well.

Comment: If you look at the code for the utility, it is a wrapper around the DSPJRN command.  It says the output file has the same fields as the journaled file plus the journal info. Why it takes so much code, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure or function with some wrapper code to call the [Retrieve Journal Entries (QjoRetrieveJournalEntries) API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/QJORJRNE.htm)

Comment: Yes but there is a ready-made IBM solution via a UDTF - see my other response